# Symfony ElasticaBundle query_builder_method

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, foselasticabundle

I need upload in elastic Lead inly who have status approved, this is my, mapping:

```
                 persistence:
                      driver: orm
                      model: Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Lead
                      provider:
                        query_builder_method: createIsActiveQueryBuilder
                      listener: ~
                      finder: ~
```

and my query_builder_method: createIsActiveQueryBuilder:

```
public function createIsActiveQueryBuilder()
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');

    $qb
        ->select('d')
        ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Lead', 'd')
        ->where('d.statusLead = :status')
        ->setParameter('status', 'approved')
    ;

    return $qb;
}
```

But when I run

```
app/console fos:elastica:populate --no-reset
```

I read in doc

```
Your repository must implement this method and return a Doctrine query builder.
```

in my DB I have two lead with status not_approved and when I change one for approved everything ok I have one lead in elastic. But if in DB I dont have lead with status approved I have error all time ?

but have error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long $code [, Exception $previous = NULL]]]) in /home/ivan/host/aog-code/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Exception/ResponseException.php on line 34

 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                                                   
 Error: Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long $code [, Exception $previous = NULL]]])
```

And when I create new Lead with default status 'not_approved' this lead uploaded in elastic, why I not understand listener upload this lead, why not work query_builder ?

why not understand, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The message states you should return QueryBuilder instance. By calling:

```
$query = $qb->getQuery();
return $query;
```

you're returning a Query instance from your QueryBuilder

Your function should read:

```
public function createIsActiveQueryBuilder() {
  $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');
  return $qb
    ->select('d')
    ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Lead', 'd')
    ->where('d.statusLead = :status')
    ->setParameter('status', 'approved');
}
```

Comment: I have error because have two space before query_builder_method, I update my question

Comment: I see return all QueryBuilder but have error. 

 
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Error: Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long $code [, Exception $previous = NULL]]])

Comment: in my DB I have two lead with status not_approved and when I change one for approved everything ok I have one lead in elastic. But if in DB I dont have lead with status approved I have error all time ?

Comment: and when I create new lead with status not_approved this lead upload in elastic :( why not work query_builder ?